# Blazor server app with client API processing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am trying to build a web application that will also have a API. Login and user management is done by B2C. The following is the code used for authentication and enabling API endpoints.

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
       {
           builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

           //  options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
       },
options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });


builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

Login page works fine by launching B2C login flow. Authentication works fine. Postman returns login page html as response when requested with token.

What is needed is:

1. Login link to show B2c Login UI
2. API to work with token
3. Launch website using access token like : https://localhost:7135/?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC

Item 1 works with no issue. Item 2 and 3 not working.